# How to show --select-- in CakePHP form helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to show --Select-- as the default value using the CakePHP form helper, and for this value to be selected by default.

Current code:

```
echo $this->Form->month('m');
echo $this->Form->day('d');
echo $this->Form->year('y');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more correct than shaikh's answer:

```
echo $this->Form->month('m', array('empty' => __('-- Select --')));
```

Doesn't require javascript and is easily translated in the future. This is all clearly written in the [API reference](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelpermonth).

Answer (score -4):

You might Use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#UserCreatedMonth :nth-child(1)').text('-- Select --');
$('#UserCreatedDay :nth-child(1)').text('-- Select --');
$('#UserCreatedYear :nth-child(1)').text('-- Select --');
</script>
```

Comment: It's completely unnecessary to use JavaScript to do this in CakePHP since CakePHP already provides functionality to deal with this. The question didn't call for a JS solution either.